# Getting max and min from BST (C++ vs Java)

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I know that given a balanced binary search tree, getting the min and max element takes O(logN), I want to ask about their implementation in C++ and Java respectively.

C++

Take `std::set` for example, getting min/max can be done by calling `*set.begin()` / `*set.rbegin()` , and it's constant time.

Java

Take `HashSet` for example, getting min/max can be done by calling `HashSet.first()` and `HashSet.last()`, but it's logarithmic time.

I wonder if this is because `std::set` has done some extra trick to always update the `beigin()` and `rbegin()` pointer, if so, can anyone show me that code? Btw why didn't Java add this trick too, it seems pretty convenient to me...

EDIT:

My question might not be very clear, I want to see how `std::set` implements insert/erase , I'm curious to see how the `begin()` and `rbegin()` iterator are updated during those operations..

EDIT2:

I'm very confused now. Say I have following code:

```
set<int> s;

s.insert(5);
s.insert(3);
s.insert(7);
... // say I inserted a total of n elements.
s.insert(0);
s.insert(9999);

cout<<*s.begin()<<endl;  //0
cout<<*s.rbegin()<<endl; //9999
```

Isn't both `*s.begin()` and `*s.rbegin()` O(1) operations? Are you saying they aren't? s.rbegin() actually iterate to the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer isn't language specific. 
To fetch the `MIN` or `MAX` in a `BST`, you need to always iterate till the leftmost or the rightmost node respectively. This operation in `O(height)`, which may roughly be `O(log n)`.

Now, to optimize this retrieval, a class that implements `Tree` can always store two extra pointers pointing to the leftmost and the rightmost node and then retrieving them becomes `O(1)`. Off course, these pointers brings in the overhead of updating them with each insert operation in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

`begin()` and `rbegin()` only return iterators, in constant time. Iterating them isn't constant-time.

There is no '`begin()/rbegin()` pointer'. The min and max are reached by iterating to the leftmost or rightmost elements, just as in Java, only Java doesn't have the explicit iterator.

Comment: sure, I'm just interested in min/max value, so I'm curious about how those iterators are updated during insert/erase, because it seems smarter than Java's implementation..

Comment: They're not. They just iterate to the leftmost or rightmost element, same as Java.

Comment: I checked the API it says calling both `set.begin()` and `set.rbegin()` are constant time, therefore I can get the max element by calling `*set.rbegin()`, no?    For Java, I think you can also get the min element using iterator, but getting the max element would require iterating through all elements (linear time) or calling `HashSet.last()` (logarithmic time) , that's why I say it's more convenient for C++... Anything wrong?

Comment: I'm confused when you say "The min and max are reached by iterating to the leftmost or rightmost elements" , maybe I misunderstand `rbegin()`? I've updated my question with an example..